# Jquery mobile and Android integration

Tags: jquery, android

I have fair knowledge of Android and sometimes had played with Jquery.
Now I want to develop a Android app with Jquery mobile but not sure how it works together.
Can anybody please share some good link to work with Android and Jquery mobile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Tool for the job: http://www.phonegap.com/

easy to get going, and if you need native code, there are lots of plugins to choose from

Comment: Can you please mention some of your favorite plugins ?

Comment: really depends on the app you are writing ... for me camera access and nfc were real timesavers

Comment: I will playing with barcode scanning and remote servers syncing.